# Do analog to digital lens adapters exist (to pass EXIF data to a camera)?

Tags: lens, metadata, digital

What I'm envisioning is a lens adapter that could be used for multiple (film-era) lenses on a modern digital camera, but would allow you to enter your custom lens info into the adapter so that, when shooting, you can tell the adapter what lens is in use (and what the aperture setting is), via simple button selection on the adapter. Otherwise, when using such lenses, I have keep notes and add that information later, on the computer. It would be so cool to be able to add EXIF lens info, in-camera, when shooting with lenses that don't have any electronic connection to the camera. Has anyone heard of such a thing, or is this just a pipe dream? (Most of my other "pipe dreams" seem to show up as products, but I haven't seen this one yet... )

Comment: Maybe this could be done with some sort of phone app, where you can record the lens details etc. Then that could sync with your photos to add the EXIF afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen such adapters for Canon and Nikon mounts. Never used them, but I recall one of them has the name Dandelion or something like that. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelion_chip

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I didn't know if such a thing existed, but hoped it did and now I know what to call it. I'm hoping to find one that will allow me to use CONTAX (C/Y mount) lenses from the 70s–90s on Sony FE. Thanks again! :-)